# what if user deletes some file from installed folder

Tags: deployment

I have created windows application setup using Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate, .Net Framework version 4.0 and Access database ,It is getting installed properly in default location ,but I want to know what if user deletes some file or data from this location ,what can I do for this ?what is the right way?

Comment: You could calculate a checksum of your installation directory and use it to ensure that no files have been modified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have *many choices* to do that:

### 1. Use the Compiled Executable Version of Your MS Access Database File.

You can **compile your database into an Executable File**.

But I don't know that you can access to it from other Programming Languages like C# or not. I think you must search the Internet.

- **In MS Access 2013:**

  Go to the *File* -> *Save As* -> *Save Database As* -> *Make ACCDE* "File will be compiled into an executable only file."

[image: Make an Executable file from the database.]
[image: Save the Executable file of the database in somewhere.]

- **In MS Access 2010:**

  Go to the *File* -> *Save & Publish* -> *Save Database As* -> *Make ACCDE*
- **In MS Access 2007:**

  Go to the *Database Tools* ribbon tab -> *Make ACCDE* (in the Database Tools group)

### 2. Encrypt Database with the Password.

You can **save your MS Access database file with Password**; in this way, *you must set the Password in database connection string for accessing to it.*

- **In MS Access 2013:**

  Go to the *File* -> *Info* -> *Encrypt with Password* "Use a password to restrict access to your database. Files that use the 2007 Microsoft Access file format or later are encrypted."

[image: Open File Menu.]
[image: Open the database file.]
[image: Open the database file in Exclusive mode.]
[image: Encrypt the database file with Password.]
[image: Add Password to the database for Encrypting.]

Go to the *File* -> *Info* -> *Decrypt Database* "Removes the password from this database."

[image: Decrypt the database file.]
[image: Enter Password for Decrypting database file.]

- **In MS Access 2010:**

  Go to the *File* -> *Info* -> *Encrypt with Password*

  Go to the *File* -> *Info* -> *Decrypt Database*
- **In MS Access 2007:**

  Go to the *Database Tools* ribbon tab -> *Encrypt with Password* (in the Database Tools group)

  Go to the *Database Tools* ribbon tab -> *Decrypt Database* (in the Database Tools group)

### 3. Backup Your Main Database.

You can **create a backup version of your database in somewhere else**; you can do this with two ways:

1. Write some codes for create a backup file from your database *with the backup ability of the MS Access*. You can do this *manually* from MS Access program:

   - **In MS Access 2013:**

     Go to the *File* -> *Save As* -> *Save Database As* -> *Back Up Database* "Back up important database regularly to prevent data loss."

   [image: Create a Backup file from the database.]
   [image: Save the Backup file of the database in somewhere.]

   - **In MS Access 2010:**

     Go to the *File* -> *Save & Publish* -> *Save Database As* -> *Back Up Database*
   - **In MS Access 2007:**

     Go to the *Microsoft Office Button* -> *Manage* -> *Back Up Database* (under Manage this database)
2. For creating A backup file, you can simply *create a copy of your file* with writing some codes to do that.

The scenario for doing both is as follows:

Add or Call your codes for *closing time of your application program* that is closed by the end-user. *Run your codes in the background Thread(s).* Copy or back up it in somewhere like as follows:

- *%WINDIR%..\ProgramData\YourSubFolder(s)*
- *%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\YourSubFolder(s)*
- *%USERPROFILE%\AppData\LocalLow\YourSubFolder(s)*
- *%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Roaming\YourSubFolder(s)*
- *Somewhere else like:*

  - *Another folder in your program root folder or sub-folders(s)*
  - *Another folder in where you want*
- *Etc.*

**Hint:** You can *change attributes of your database file* (in the root folder or sub-folder(s) of your program) *and/or its backup file* (in somewhere else) to the **Read-only**, **Hidden**, **System**, **Read-only + Hidden**, **Read-only + System**, **Hidden + System** or **Read-only + Hidden + System** *for increasing security*.

[image: Open Properties of the database file.]
[image: Change Attributes of the database file to the Hidden.]
[image: Apply Hidden Attribute on the database file.]
[image: Change Attributes of the database file to the Read-only.]
[image: Copy the Path of the database file.]
[image: Run Windows OS Command Prompt.]
[image: Open Windows OS Command Prompt window.]
[image: Type "attrib +h +s " with Paste the Path of the database file.]
[image: Complete typing "attrib +h +s E:\Rostami\Myself\Programming\Access"]
[image: Type Remaining Part of the database file Path (some of the initial characters [\da]).]
[image: Press "Tab" key on the keyboard for completing the name of the database file.]
[image: Press "Enter" key on the keyboard for applying Hidden + System attributes on the database file.]
[image: Change Attributes of the database file to the Hidden + System.]
[image: Apply Hidden + System Attributes on the database file.]
[image: Press "Enter" key on the keyboard for applying System attribute on the database file.]
[image: Change Attributes of the database file to the System.]
[image: Apply System Attribute on the database file.]
[image: Press "Enter" key on the keyboard for removing Hidden + System attributes on the database file.]
[image: Remove Hidden + System Attributes from the database file.]
[image: Apply none Attribute on the database file.]

- You can't see Hidden files in default mode of displaying items; so, for see Hidden items, you must do the following:

[image: Show Hidden items from Folders Ribbon.]

or

[image: Open Folder Options dialogue box.]
[image: Show Hidden items from Folder Options dialogue box.]

- You can't see System files in default mode of displaying items; so, for see System items, you must do the following:

[image: Show System items.]
[image: Confirm to show System items.]

With doing this scenario, you can add some codes for running in the start-up time of your program for checking *is there Database in its folder or not*. And if it can't find the main database, *just copy your database simply from backup folder to its initial folder* in your application folder/sub-folder(s).

### 4. Change the Security Attributes of the Main and Backup Database.

You can **change the security attributes for the Main Database** (in the root folder or sub-folder(s) of your program) **and its backup file** (in somewhere else) *to restrict access* to both of them as follows:

Add or Call your codes in *closing time of your application program* that is closed by the end-user. *Run your codes after completing background Thread(s) for backup the Main Database (if you're used Backup Scenario).* These codes must change the Security attributes to the **specific Windows OS or User-defined** (must define by you if you want to use it) **Group or User**. With this method, *when program isn't running, no one can access to both database files.*

Remember that you must add or call some codes for changing the Security attributes of both databases in start-up time of your application program; because they must accessible by the application.

[image: Open Windows OS Computer Management window.]
[image: Open New User window.]
[image: Create new user.]
[image: Create a new user with entered data.]
[image: Open new user Properties window.]
[image: Remove all items that new user is member of them.]
[image: Add new item for that new user becomes member of it.]
[image: Find Administrators Group.]
[image: Add Administrators Group.]
[image: Apply changes to new user.]

If you want to use a Group, you can do the following:

[image: Open New Group window.]
[image: Add data and Members.]
[image: Show Advanced part of the Select Users window.]
[image: Find Users or Built-in security principals.]
[image: Find new User.]
[image: Add new User.]
[image: Create new group.]
[image: Create a new group with entered data.]

[image: Open Properties window of the database file.]
[image: Open Advanced Security Settings window of the database file.]
[image: Disable inheritance.]
[image: Remove all inherited permissions from the database file.]
[image: Change Owner.]
[image: Save Changes.]
[image: Confirm to apply changes.]
[image: Find new User.]
[image: Add new User.]
[image: Open Permission Entry window of the database file.]
[image: Select a principal.]
[image: Find new User.]
[image: Add new User.]
[image: Apply Changes.]
[image: Apply Changes.]
[image: Apply Changes.]

[image: You can't open the database file.]
[image: Provide administrator permission to delete the database file.]
[image: You can't delete the database file.]
[image: Provide administrator permission to copy the database file.]
[image: You can't copy the database file.]
[image: Provide administrator permission to move the database file.]
[image: You can't move the database file.]
[image: Open Properties window of the database file.]
[image: You can't see the properties of the database file.]

In order of what I mentioned above, **THE BEST SOLUTION IS:**

- ***Hybrid method:***

*Combine all methods together for achieve to the better and more secure method:*

***Compiled Executable Version of the MS Access Database File*** + ***Encryption with the Password*** + ***Backing Up the Main Database*** + ***Changing Security Attributes for Both Databases***

Comment: Your answer is very clean and well explained ,thank you ,using this I came to know about database security in more depth

Comment: How does this answer this original question?